# How to enable/disable scrolling in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scrollview

I know about this command:

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = true
```

The question is: I want to lock scrolling according to the scrollView position. For this I do:

```
let topEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let followersViewEdge = CGRectGetHeight(self.profileView.frame) - 50

    if topEdge >= followersViewEdge {
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = true
    }
```

it works, but the problem is that it does not lock or unlock the scrolling immediately. For locking or unlocking the UITableView scrolling I need to release my finger from the screen and scroll again. In this case it works.

I want to make it immediately, so it locks and unlocks the scrolling while I'm swiping on the screen. How can I do it?

**UPDATE**

My code works. It's not a problem. Problem is that I need to make these changes immediately, without releasing my finger from the screen.

So, do not answer me how to lock scrolling! I know how to do this.

Comment: try `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate ?

Comment: @zcui93 my code works. So, yes, I already connected delegate. Please, read carefully

Comment: Nothing you said mentioned that.

Comment: @JohnDoe did you find a solution? I am facing the exact same issue where I need un-interrupted scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select tableview
2. choose Attribute insepector
3. In scroll view section, uncheck Scrolling Enabled property

Comment: My code works. It's not a problem. Problem is that I need to make these changes immediately, without releasing my finger from the screen

Comment: Is it your tableview is subview on scroll view?

Answer (score 1):

Force the `contentOffset` to your max value while scrolling :

```
let topEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y
let followersViewEdge = CGRectGetHeight(self.profileView.frame) - 50

if topEdge >= followersViewEdge {
    self.tableView.contentOffset.y = followersViewEdge
}
```

Comment: and what it will give me?

Comment: it will give you what you asked, ie a tableView that can't scroll more than the value `followersViewEdge`

Comment: no, it does not help me at all. It works the same and in addition scrolls my content to the bottom

Comment: then you have to use an other value than `followersViewEdge`, maybe your `50` hardcoded pixels, but I can't help more with the code you've given.

Comment: it does not work and without it. It works as my code worked before

Answer (score 0):

You need to setting up the pan gesture recognizer for your table view and keep listening listener.

By you approach can lock it.

```
    if topEdge >= followersViewEdge {
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = true
    }
```

By the pan gesture recognizer, you can lock/unlock it.

```
    if(self.tableView.scrollEnabled) {
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false
    } else {
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = true
    }
```

**Example**

```
     // Added the Pan Recognizer for capture the touches
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panReconizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panReconizer:)];
    panReconizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = panReconizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:panReconizer];


    - (void)panReconizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan {
         NSLog(@" ..............  pan detected!! ...................");
         if(self.tableView.scrollEnabled) {
            self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false
        } else {
            self.tableView.scrollEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: after changing scrollEnabled I need to release my finger from the screen and scroll again. I want to make it as continue of the single scroll

Comment: Now I undstd your usecase, then you should use pan gesture. Pls refer above updated example.

Comment: You suggest to make changes on touch. In addition it requires another touch to use the tableView. So, that's not what I need. Do you use Twitter iOS app? I want to create like Profile page screen